# How to redirect video stream in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, video-streaming, windows-media-services, expression-encoder-4

let suppose there is a continuous http video stream (encoding is H.264) comming from a camera which URL is

http://xyz.com/videostream

due to some security reasons I can not expose this URL to my users (or assume this is accessible only with in intranet) so now I want to redirect this stream to another URL using ASP.Net application which is accessible to my users.

http://abc.com/y

Suggest a way to achieving this using ASP.NET 4.0 & IIS 7.5 or with any other open source plugin or with Expression Encoder.
Is it possible to use some URL masking for this?

Comment: Is that continuos video strem?

Comment: yes, it is continuous http video stream coming from camera. Edited my question.

Comment: Can you explain what "some security reasons" are and how much control over it you have?

Comment: http://xyz.com/videostream is not accessible by outside world. I have full control on the server & application (including source code which is in ASP.NET) where http://abc.com/y is hosted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still searching for the best answer but below links helped me:

http://www.cctvcamerapros.com/Embedding-IP-Camera-Web-Page-s/326.htm

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/620/getting-started-with-iis-live-smooth-streaming/

http://www.red5.org/